# Cluster network map of keyword python

Tags: python, networking, graph, keyword

I would like to create a network graph with the most occured keyword that I have just extrapolated from various paper. So I have an excel file with this keywords and I would rappresent their connections and frequency.
I have already create a graph with nx.draw, but the result is very confused and illegible...any suggestions ?
Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: key_graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(key, source="first", target="second")
best_conn_k=nx.betweenness_centrality(key_graph) 
most_imp_k=nx.eigenvector_centrality(key_graph)
lt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
nx.draw(key_graph, with_labels=True,node_color='c', node_size= [v*100 for v in dict(key_graph.degree).values()], width=[v*10 for v in dict(most_imp_k).values()])